# How does Laravel/Lumen verifies the authentication of a user through JWT?

Tags: laravel, authentication, jwt, lumen

I'm new to Laravel and JWT-auth. I've implemented the process of generating JWT tokens and getting the associated user in my back-end, but I'm still can not understand how the server verifies the authentication of a user from just a token stored on the client side.

If I log in on machine A and change my password on machine B, can I still log in from machine A with the previous token?

Comment: . The token isn't linked to a password but rather to a user directly so it's in the discretion of the JWT provider how they'll handle password changes.

Comment: @apokryfos Thanks for your reply. That makes sense to me. By saying JWT provider, do you mean the jwt-auth plugin or the back-end developer himself? Anyway, could you give me some hints about a good practice of implementation?

Comment: In this case the JWT provider is your application so you can basically force an invalidate of all tokens associated with a user whenever a user changes their password, if you want ([Observers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#observers) are helpful here) .

Comment: @apokryfos Thanks, mate. It clears my doubts.

Answer (score 0):

You have a 'users' table and generally another table like 'sessions'. When a user makes a request to login through your API, a new line into the 'sessions' table is inserted (the token is saved) and the API return the token to the user. For all requests that need authentification, the user will have to give this token (through HTTP header for example).

When you want to authentificate a user on a request you have to verify if the token exists and remains valid and then retrieve the user. Example in Lumen :

```
$this->app['auth']->viaRequest('api', function ($request) {
    $session = Session::where(['token' => $request->header('token')])->get(); //user gives his token in the header request
    if($session){
        return $session->user(); //you have setup the hasOne/hasMany relationship between sessions and users
        //the user is authenticated
    }
    return null;
    // the user is not authenticated
});
```

"If I log in on machine A and change my password on machine B, can I still log in from machine A with the previous token?"
If the token is still valid and you allow multiple active sessions then yes. The token isn't set depending of the password.